# Load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming

I am using that library visits https://github.com/piemonte/Player for playing HLS video in IOS. My all videos are in AWS S3 bucket. it is working fine.

Now I need to jump in a specific time of video. So I am using below written below:

```
 self.player.seek(to: targetTime, completionHandler: nil)
```

But I am getting following error.

> Task <99ECD3D0-64AC-4FED-9997-7008A462CD35>.<28> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3.ap-xxx-1.amazonaws.com/segment-2.ts, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.ap-xxx-1.amazonaws.com/segment-2.ts, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask <99ECD3D0-64AC-4FED-9997-7008A462CD35>.<28>"

I have also added it in info.plist but not working.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: You must be having the .m3u8 playlist file, you can you this playlist to seek your video.

Comment: @NirbhaySingh Yes i have .m3u8 file. this file creates many segments files.